Out of Memory Exception throwing when add one million records to a list before Saving using EF
Trying to save one million records into a SQL server table using EF Core. First reading the one million record from a staging table and store into a List then using the EF Core's AddRangeAsync function to save the data from the list. Here is the code block
    var importJobValidations = new List<ImportJobValidation>();
    importJobValidations.AddRange(
        (from stg in stagingUnits.AsEnumerable()
        select new ImportJobValidation
        {
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            StudyProductStagingID = stg.Id,
            IsValidationSuccessful = !errors.Exists(e => e.StagingId == stg.Id),
            Type = "UPLOAD",
            IsActive = true,
            CreatedBy = userId,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
        }));
    await _supplyManagementHangFireContext.AddRangeAsync(importJobValidations);
    await _supplyManagementHangFireContext.SaveChangesAsync();

the stagingUnits is an IQueryable. The above code block throwing an Out of memory exception.
What would be the best way to fix the out of memory exception in this scenario.

Why do you need the list, why not add the objects directly to _supplyManagementHangFireContext? Have you considered just doing an INSERT ... SELECT ... raw SQL command?

^^ Seconded: If both tables are in the same DB, why not have the db do the work and avoid transfer of all that data?

What is errors? Where does it come from?

save one million records that's the real problem. That's simply wrong. ORMs are not meant for ETL jobs. A DbContext is a Unit of Work, not a database connection. What database are you using? What is stagingUnits ? BTW the way it's writtne, the current code may create 2M in-memory objects, never mind the tracking records. 1M in sagingUnits, 1M in importJobValidations. You could avoid the intermediate copies if you passed the LINQ query, or at least the query after calling .AsEnumerable to AddRangeAsync.

@PanagiotisKanavos the process is reading one million row of recrods from Excel/csv file and store it on a staging table and do some business validations against existing data as well as duplication check on the staging data then capture the validation error for each row of records in the file then keep that error in another data store. Finally, store the validation success results stored in a permanent table.

In that case, ORMs are the exact wrong solution.  What database are you targetting? It matters a LOT. SQL Server has SSIS for what you described, which is a lot faster than any C# solution. SqlBulkCopy accepts a DbDataReader as argument, which can easily be a CsvDataReader. You can use ExcelDataReader or CsvDataReader to read the data as a stream of records, process them as a stream and finally send that stream to the database. There's no reason to load everything into memory

duplication check that's done in the staging table, not the application.

Wait, so while the data is coming from Excel / CSV, you first import into a table, right? And validation errors are also written to that db? So all of the information is present in the db? If so, then this can be done in the db.

That too. 1M rows isn't a lot these days and can just be imported into a staging table, then processed before getting copied to the productino table. All databases have bulk import features for CSVs - they're just text files after all. Excel is trickier, but there are tools to just import the data too.

@Fildor Yes, the Excel/CSV file data stored in a SQL staging table, and I suggested to do the business validation and rest of the process in a SQL Stored Procedure, but the management recommonded to use the EF

" but the management recommonded to use the EF" - seriously? What does "management" base their recommendation on? Do they have a background in software development? When was the last time they wrote 1 line of code? Also: "recommend" does not mean "ordered to", right?

@AbleAlias there's no such thing as Excel/CSV. What do you really use? And what's the actual database? CSV files aren't excel files, they're just text files that can be imported directly into the database with BULK INSERT or bcp if you use SQL Server. Other databases have other commands. Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML data. With SSIS you can perform a lot of processing while loading the data, including lookups, calculating columns etc.

If you use PostgreSQL, Npgsql also offers ways to bulk copy data to the database. For MySQL, the MySqlConnector package has MySqlBulkCopy

@PanagiotisKanavos I would like to say, it is not a single process it has two process, first is Upload, in this process includes the following steps, 1.upload the file, 2.validate the data format, 3. store the file data into staging table, 4. Validate the staged data against exist data as well as staged data, 5. store the validation error results. Then next the Import process, so user want to see the Validation Error Results before import the staged data. Again on the import process do the data data validation against the previous stored data (multi million records).  So, UI also involved.

You aren't describing anything special. I have to load millions of rows from quirky formats, not just CSVs or excel files (actual xlsx files), for at least 1M transactions per month. With each transaction appearing in multiple sources. And the jobs run every 1 hour. The database has reached 800GB, so I'm looking at partitioning next. It doesn't matter what the process is, there's no reason to use an ORM and definitely no reason to load 1M rows at once in memory. Store errors in an Error column or a separate table and display them as a report or view.

Did your manager tell you to load everything in memory, or did they say to display the errors in a grid? That doesn't mean loading everything in memory. The report page can read 1 page of data at a time and display it, allowing people to move from one page to the next. There's no way to display 1M rows in a screen, so why load it at all? Add enough filters to the report page so people can quickly find what they want instead of scrolling through 1M rows. People scroll when they can't find what they want.

I agree, there is no reason to use ORM, eventually we will move out from ORM atleast for this process, but meantime I have to fix this :)

You can only "fix" this by reducing the amount of data in your memory (at a given point in time). How to do that is a question of how soon you need to present it and what the expectations are regarding maintainability and quality and performance.

^^ Meaning: Fast and "dirty" would be to chunkify. But then you buy memory with execution time. Any "more clever" solution would cost more development time ...

A relatively quick "fix" would be: split the work into manageable chunks (say, 10k records each) - insert that much, and then start afresh with a new data context entirely. The Enumerable.Chunk extension method might make this trivial:
foreach (var chunk in stagingUnits.AsEnumerable().Chunk(10_000))
{
    using var ctx = new YourDataContextHere(...);
    var toAdd =
        (from stg in chunk
        select new ImportJobValidation
        {
            Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
            StudyProductStagingID = stg.Id,
            IsValidationSuccessful = !errors.Exists(e => e.StagingId == stg.Id),
            Type = "UPLOAD",
            IsActive = true,
            CreatedBy = userId,
            CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
        });
    await ctx.AddRangeAsync(toAdd);
    await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}


If you're adding that much data, you might prefer to drop a few levels of abstraction and look at SqlBulkCopy, perhaps using a tool like FastMember or DapperAOT to turn the IEnumerable<T> into an IDataReader suitable for streaming use; for example (similar to here):
using var reader = TypeAccessor.CreateDataReader(stagingUnits.AsEnumerable(),
    /* TODO: property names to include */);

using var table = new SqlBulkCopy(connection)
{
    DestinationTableName = "YourTableHere",
    ColumnMappings =
    {
        // TODO: specify column-property map
    }
};
table.EnableStreaming = true;
table.WriteToServer(reader);
return table.RowsCopied;


That's not a quickfix, that's the full solution

I do have the suspicion that the work could possibly be shifted into the db entirely without transferring all that data.

@PanagiotisKanavos meh, I still like the "drop to raw TDS" approach when getting to this volume

@Fildor oh, if they're in the same database - or at least the same server: absolutely; this is an INSERT+SELECT, job done

SqlBulkCopy can accept a DataReader too, so that's almost raw TDS. With lots of data, INSERT ... SELECT can choke up because of the extra locking on the source table all the transaction log records generated. Unless it's minimally logged. For million-level jobs streaming (the way SSIS does) can be a lot faster.

I could suggest paginating the result and save records in batches:
var batchSize = 1000;
var batchCount = 1000000 / batchSize;

for (var i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
{
    var query = from stg in stagingUnits.AsEnumerable()
    select new ImportJobValidation
    {
        Guid = Guid.NewGuid(),
        StudyProductStagingID = stg.Id,
        IsValidationSuccessful = !errors.Exists(e => e.StagingId == stg.Id),
        Type = "UPLOAD",
        IsActive = true,
        CreatedBy = userId,
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow
    };
    
    var batch = await query.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize).ToArrayAsync();
    // AddRangeAsync is not recommended to be used.
    _supplyManagementHangFireContext.AddRange(batch);
    await _supplyManagementHangFireContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}

AddRangeAsync is not recommended in standard operations. From docs:

This method is async only to allow special value generators, such as the one used by 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.SequenceHiLo', to access the database asynchronously. For all other cases the non async method should be used.


Batching wont' fix the fundamental problem that ORMs are simply not meant for this.

I really do have the feeling this leads in a wrong direction, in this specific case.
